# In a dynamic string, how to start a substring at a certain character and end it at certain character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have string in javascript.

```
var string = "BLAH BLAH BLAH width: 673px; height: 123px; BLAH BLAH BLAH width: 1009px; height: 237px; BLAH BLAH"
```

I want to have two substrings come out of this. One that starts at `'width'` and end at `'px'` and one that starts at `'height'` and ends at `'px'`.

This will happened for each pair of `'width'` and `'height'`. This can appear n amount of times in my string. Each time with different numbers for width and height.

I really don't know how to go about this since the string is dynamic in length. I can't just start a `substring` or `substr` at a certain index and go to a certain index. I don't see how I could use a `split` and `join` either. Is there anyway to do this with jQuery or javascript.

my current way is very slow...

```
for (var w = 1; w <= 10000; w++) {
        for(var h = 1; h<=10000; h++)
        {
            var match = text.match("style=\"width: " + w + "px; height: " + h + "px;");
            if (match != null) {
                text = text.split("style=\"width: " + w + "px; height: " + h + "px;").join('');
            }
        }
    }
```

After the substrings are found I want them to be removed from my string.

Comment: I see you've tagged the question `regex` so you're familiar with the term - I don't supposed you've tried writing one? - they're suited to this scenario.  Also *(reading between the lines)*, it looks like you're parsing an HTML style attribute - has this text come from an element sitting in the live DOM tree as a cleaner way of fetching these values would be making use of the [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method.

Comment: I tried regex, I don't know if there is a way of combining text plus the \d+ expression for the numbers.

Comment: @GlobalJim , can you give an example for multiple occurences of `width` and `height` and can they interleave each other?

Comment: The numbers will be random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After edits, you can simply do this for your requirements:

```
var string = "BLAH BLAH BLAH width: 673px; height: 123px; BLAH BLAH BLAH width: 1009px; height: 237px; BLAH BLAH";
var regExp = /(\b\w+:[^:]*px)/g
string = string.replace(regExp,'')
```

With regex, you can do like this:

```
var string = "BLAH BLAH BLAH width: 673px; height: 123px; BLAH BLAH BLAH width: 1009px; height: 237px; BLAH BLAH";
var regExp = /(\b\w+:[^:]*px)/g
var match = regExp.exec(string);
while(match != null)
{
    var width = match[1]
    match = regExp.exec(string);
    var height = match[1]
    match = regExp.exec(string);
}
```

After this, In each iteration, the variable `width` will have the substring `width: 4874px` and the variable `height` will have the substring `height: 898px`

Comment: it work! but only for one instance. updating my questions sorry I should have included that

Comment: @GlobalJim , it's ok update question and i'll update answer accordingly :)

Comment: @GlobalJim , answer updated :) you'll get pair in each iteration

Comment: I get an error: 'Unable to get property '1' of undifned or null reference'

Comment: @GlobalJim , can you post the string on which you got the error?

Comment: I updated question. I need to remove the matches from my string. Your code works as intended but when I remove the matches that's when it throws an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81466/discussion-between-pruthvi-raj-and-globaljim).

Comment: @GlobalJim , check the answer and try the first code snippet, it fits what u are trying to do

Answer (score 2):

An elegant way to extract string between two others is to add a function to String object.

```js
    /**
     * Extract a string between a Prefix and a Suffix
     *
     * @param prefix {string} Prefix string
     * @param suffix {string} Suffix string
     * @param trimSpace {boolean} (optional default false) is string space trimmed
     * @returns {string} String between prefix and suffix
     */
    String.prototype.between = function(prefix, suffix, trimSpace) {
      trimSpace = typeof trimSpace !== 'undefined' ? trimSpace : false;

      var thisString = this;
      var index = thisString.indexOf(prefix);
      if (index >= 0) {
        thisString = thisString.substring(index + prefix.length);
      } else {
        return "";
      }
      if (suffix) {
        index = thisString.indexOf(suffix);
        if (index < 0) {
          return "";
        } else {
          thisString = thisString.substring(0, index);
        }
      }
      return trimSpace ? thisString.trim() : thisString;
    }

    var theString = "*Other text that is dynamic in length* width: 4874px; height: 898px *more dynamic length text*"

    var width = theString.between("width:", "px");
    var widthTrimmed = theString.between("width:", "px", true);
    var heightTrimmed = theString.between("height:", "px", true);
    
    document.write("Not trimmed width: width=>" + width + "<" + "<br/>");
    document.write("Trimmed width: widthTrimmed=>" + widthTrimmed + "<" + "<br/>");
    document.write("Trimmed height: heightTrimmed=>" + heightTrimmed + "<" + "<br/>");
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the format remains the same getting the index of width/height and px should be enough

```js
var string = "*Other text that is dynamic in length* width: 4874px; height: 898px; *more dynamic length text*";

var windexStart=string.indexOf('width')+6;
var windexStop=string.indexOf('px;');
var hindexStart=string.indexOf('height')+7;
var hindexStop=string.lastIndexOf('px;');


var width=string.substring(windexStart,windexStop);
var height=string.substring(hindexStart,hindexStop);
alert(width+' '+height);
```

Comment: the numbers could be anywhere from 1-10000

Comment: Ah I see. yes both with px;. sorry I left off the ; in question.